# How to find tables with two column names in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a table in a database that has two column names. If I try to search the DB for a table with one column name I am able to pull back a list of table names that has that column, but when I do it for 2 columns I pull back nothing.

Here is what I have been using:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'COLUMN_1' and column_name = 'COLUMN_2'
```

Comment: Either GROUP BY, or self join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` or `IN`.
Then grouped by the table_name, it should be having 2 columns.

**MySql**

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name IN ('COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2') 
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 2
```

**Oracle Database**

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE column_name IN ('COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2') 
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  :

```
select table_name
  from all_tab_columns
 where column_name = 'COLUMN_1'
   and table_name in (select table_name
                        from all_tab_columns
                       where column_name = 'COLUMN_2')
```